# Merge multiple timeseries dataframe Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, time-series

We have 20 different dataframes, each data frames contains historical stock price of company like this:

```
            Date    ISFT
0     2017-11-27  648.10
1     2017-11-28  649.90
2     2017-11-29  639.90
3     2017-11-30  697.10
4     2017-12-01  675.20
         ...     ...
1186  2022-11-15  109.00
1187  2022-11-16  117.50
1188  2022-11-17  132.85
1189  2022-11-18  133.80
1190  2022-11-21  122.65
```

We want to merge all dataframes together with key columns for the operation are 'Date' like this:

```
            Date     ISFT   CARTRADE
0     2017-11-27   648.10       NaN
1     2017-11-28   649.90       NaN
2     2017-11-29   639.90       NaN
3     2017-11-30   697.10       NaN
4     2017-12-01   675.20       NaN
         ...       ...       ...
1187  2022-11-16   117.50    502.00
1188  2022-11-17   132.85    495.35
1189  2022-11-18   133.80    490.65
1190  2022-11-21   122.65    489.70
1191  2022-10-13      NaN    588.80
```

how can we do this for 20 dataframes in the quickliest way? Thank you.

We tried to use a For-loop by looping through the list of dataframes and merge the new columns to the previous dataframe. However, it doesn't work.

```
df_list = [PACE, NYKAA,ASRL, ZOMATO]

for i in df_list:
    df_merge = df_merge.merge(i, on = 'Date', how = 'outer')
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `Date` into the index and use `pd.concat` to join the frames:

```py
pd.concat([df.set_index("Date") for df in df_list], axis=1)
```

Comment: we tried using .concate but we can not get it in ascending order and some values are showing NaN, which actually have a value